# How do I store hex values in char* variables in c

Tags: pointers, char, hex

I have the following variables

`char *key;`

`char*text;`

I want to store hex value `0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` in `key`
and I want to store hex value `0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD` in text.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: char *key = [0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA];   

char *text = "0xDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD ";

Comment: `char *key = [0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA]; ` doesn't work. Compiler says unexpected "["

Comment: Replace these by brackets, my bad.